# django project: isort ignores local .cfg file's "skip" parameter

Tags: django, isort

I'm using "isort" in my Django project and the problem is when I make the isort command on the project level it ignores app-level ".isort.cfg" file's skip parameters.

My isort version is 5.11.4.
The local/app level ".isort.cfg" file:

> ```
> [settings]
> known_django=django
> sections=FUTURE,STDLIB,DJANGO,THIRDPARTY,FIRSTPARTY,LOCALFOLDER
> skip=migrations
> ```

How to force it to not ignore nested folders cfg files?

Results for command "isort . --resolve-all-configs --verbose
" is a long list(no errors) like following:
./orders/.isort.cfg used for file ./orders/migrations/0001_initial.py
./orders/.isort.cfg used for file ./orders/migrations/**init**.py

As seen here it 'uses' app-level cfg file but 'migrations' files are not ignored as it should be according the app-level config.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `--resolve-all-configs` to your isort command. More information in the doc section [Supporting multiple config files in single isort run](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/config_files.html#custom-config-files).

For example in my multi-app django-project I have a .isort.cfg at root level, and I added the .isort.cfg file in my settings folder. Here is the output I get with following command: `isort --verbose --resolve-all-configs .`

```
.\.isort.cfg used for file .\project\views\project.py # root config file
.\settings\.isort.cfg used for file .\settings\asgi.py # nested config file
```

Comment: Thanx, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Tried: "isort --resolve-all-configs .". migrations not ignored but when running nested one are ignored. seems bug(

Comment: Can you add output of `isort --resolve-all-configs --verbose`  to your question ?

Comment: I do the same. Does it skip files mentioned in nested configs when run from root?

Comment: Do you want to mix configuration files ? Like isort should apply both rules from top config file and nested config file ? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: seems so. tried extend_skip=migrations in the nested file, doesn't help. Well, thank you for trying to help